# Return array of objects from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of salesRecord, such as

```
const clientRecord = [
  {clientNumber: "3232",record: [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}]},
  {clientNumber: "12345",record: [{a:7, b:8},{a:9, b:0}]},
]
```

I want to return an array of record objects form this array such as

```
const records = [
  {{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}}, 
  {{a:7, b:8},{a:9, b:0}}
]
```

How do I accomplish this in javascript.
I want to avoid nested loops while implementing this.

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Invalid expected output

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, array.map will help as you have rightly mentioned @Barmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map()` to extract the `records` arrays from each object.

```
const records = clientRecords.map(rec => rec.record);
```

Answer (score 3):

The desired result you've written in the question is not a valid JS contruction:

```
const records = [
{{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}},
{{a:7, b:8},{a:9, b:0}}
]
```

You may have array of arrays, or array of all records, but in your example you have `{{..}}` construction with curly braces like object, but without any keys - that is not valid.

So, in order to get one of the valid options you can write the following code:

```js
const clientRecord = [
{clientNumber: "3232",record: [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}]},
{clientNumber: "12345",record: [{a:7, b:8},{a:9, b:0}]},
]

const records = clientRecord.map(x => x.record);

console.log(records); // [[{..}, {..}], [{..}], ... ]
```

Or, if you need to have each record being separate in the list, you can flat the array:

```js
const clientRecord = [
{clientNumber: "3232",record: [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4},{a:5, b:6}]},
{clientNumber: "12345",record: [{a:7, b:8},{a:9, b:0}]},
]

const records = clientRecord.map(x => x.record).flat();

console.log(records); // [{..},{..},{..}, ...]
```

Comment: or `.flatMap()` could be used instead of map()+flat() which is designed to flatten the resulting mapped arrays into one resulting array